# Python - reducing long if-elif lines of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started learning python, and while my code is working, I want to reduce my lines of code. I was thinking of using list method, but I couldn't really come up of a solution. I tried searching beforehand, but I couldn't find something related to mine.

For my code, it's like a point moving through one space to another. The possible movements are determined by directions. What I did to determine the movement of the point was to assign a `userPoint` (which determines where the point is). In order to move, it has to satisfy the conditions set by the space (aka the only available directions represented by `userInput.upper()`) or else it will not move and print that the input was invalid.

```
if userInput.upper() == 'QUIT':
    break
elif userPoint == 0 and userInput.upper() =='EAST':
    userPoint = 1
elif userPoint == 1 and userInput.upper() == 'WEST':
    userPoint = 0
elif userPoint == 1 and userInput.upper() == 'EAST':
    userPoint = 2
elif userPoint == 1 and userInput.upper() == 'SOUTH':
    userPoint = 4
elif userPoint == 2 and userInput.upper() == 'WEST':
    userPoint = 1
elif userPoint == 3 and userInput.upper() == 'SOUTH':
    userPoint = 6
elif userPoint == 4 and userInput.upper() == 'NORTH':
    userPoint = 1
elif userPoint == 4 and userInput.upper() == 'EAST':
    userPoint = 5
elif userPoint == 5 and userInput.upper() == 'WEST':
    userPoint = 4
elif userPoint == 5 and userInput.upper() == 'SOUTH':
    userPoint = 8
elif userPoint == 6 and userInput.upper() == 'NORTH':
    userPoint = 3
elif userPoint == 6 and userInput.upper() == 'EAST':
    userPoint = 7
elif userPoint == 7 and userInput.upper() == 'WEST':
    userPoint = 6
elif userPoint == 7 and userInput.upper() == 'EAST':
    userPoint = 8
elif userPoint == 8 and userInput.upper() == 'WEST':
    userPoint = 7
elif userPoint == 8 and userInput.upper() =='NORTH':
    userPoint = 5
else:
    print('Please input a valid direction.\n')
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it by creating a dictionary mapping
Something like this

```
mapping = {
    0 : {
        "EAST" : 1
    },
    1 : {
        "EAST": 2,
        "WEST": 1,
        "SOUTH": 4
    }
}


if userInput.upper() == 'QUIT':
    break
else:
    userInput = mapping[userPoint][userInput.upper()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that whenever `userInput` is East, the effect is to add one to `userDirection`.

You can shorten the long line, by testing for `userInput`, and calcuating `userDirection`.

```
if userInput.upper == "EAST":
    userDirection += 1
elif userInput.upper == "SOUTH":
    userDirection += 3
elif #  etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the user is moving through a sort of labyrinth that looks like this:

```
2--1--0
   |
5--4  3
|     |
8--7--6
```

We can store the valid connections as a list of sets.  For example, `{0, 1}` represents a connection that goes from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0.  Sets have no ordering, so `{0, 1}` and `{1, 0}` are the same thing.

```
if userInput.upper() == 'QUIT':
    break

connections = [{0,1}, {1,2}, {1,4}, {3,6}, {4,5}, {5,8}, {6,7}, {7,8}]

if userInput.upper() == 'EAST':
    newUserPoint = userPoint + 1
elif userInput.upper() == 'WEST':
    newUserPoint = userPoint - 1
elif userInput.upper() == 'SOUTH':
    newUserPoint = userPoint + 3
elif userInput.upper() == 'NORTH':
    newUserPoint = userPoint - 3
else:
    newUserPoint = None

movementIsValid = {userPoint, newUserPoint} in connections
if movementIsValid:
    userPoint = newUserPoint
else:
    print('Please input a valid direction.\n')
```

To learn about how lists and sets are used, you can check out the tutorial ([lists](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)).  In the code above, we calculate the new point and then check if there is a connection from the old point to the new point.

There is still some repetition that we can get rid of when we calculate the new point.

```
if userInput.upper() == 'QUIT':
    break

directions = {'EAST': 1, 'WEST': -1, 'SOUTH': 3, 'NORTH': -3}
connections = [{0,1}, {1,2}, {1,4}, {3,6}, {4,5}, {5,8}, {6,7}, {7,8}]

if userInput.upper() in directions:
    userDirection = directions[userInput.upper()]
    newUserPoint = userPoint + userDirection
else:
    newUserPoint = None

movementIsValid = {userPoint, newUserPoint} in connections
if movementIsValid:
    userPoint = newUserPoint
else:
    print('Please input a valid direction.\n')
```

In this solution, we use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for the directions.

I've used a lot of concepts that might be new for you, you can read about them in the links I've given, and if you get stuck anywhere you can ask a new question here on StackOverflow.